# Propagate max value to parent nodes in nested tree javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-lists

Having a nested array like the following one:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "idParent": null,
        "anidatedView": null,
        "state": null,
        "warningHighThreshold": null,
        "dangerHighThreshold": null,
        "lvl": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 139,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 186,
                        "idParent": 139,
                        "anidatedView": 279,
                        "state": 15.58,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 80,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 189,
                        "idParent": 139,
                        "anidatedView": 193,
                        "state": 40.65,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 80,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 140,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 193,
                        "idParent": 140,
                        "anidatedView": 183,
                        "state": 65.41,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 92,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 141,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 194,
                        "idParent": 141,
                        "anidatedView": 143,
                        "state": 60.77,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 90,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 195,
                        "idParent": 141,
                        "anidatedView": 436,
                        "state": 59.13,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 90,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I´m trying to propagate the max value of state(also warningHighThreshold and dangerHighThreshold of that max node) to all parent nodes.
State and thresholds values will be always avalable on the last level on the tree.

Any idea how to do this with recursion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean by _"propagate the max value of state"_ ? Can you provide more details or at-least share that code that you tried so far, It will give us more context about your problem...

Comment: So you want find a largest value of a specific property and copy that value to it's parent object (and to all it's parent objects)?

Comment: That's! @vanowm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

A comment pointed out a missing requirement.  Instead of capturing `state` `warningHighThreshold` and `dangerHighThreshhold` with independent maxima, we are supposed to find the descendent object with the maximum `state` and select the other two values from that object.  Here is a version that captures that requirement.

```js
const collect = (o) => {
  const kids = (o .children || []) .map (collect)
  const highest = [o, ...kids] .reduce (
    (a, x) => x.state > a.state ? x : a, 
    {state: -Infinity}
  )
  return {
    ...o,
    state: highest .state,
    warningHighThreshold: highest .warningHighThreshold,
    dangerHighThreshold: highest .dangerHighThreshold,
    children: kids,
  }
}

const collectMax = (list) => 
  list .map (collect)

const input = [{id: 100, idParent: null, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 1, children: [{id: 139, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 186, idParent: 139, anidatedView: 279, state: 15.58, warningHighThreshold: 80, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}, {id: 189, idParent: 139, anidatedView: 193, state: 40.65, warningHighThreshold: 80, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}, {id: 140, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 193, idParent: 140, anidatedView: 183, state: 65.41, warningHighThreshold: 92, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}, {id: 141, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 194, idParent: 141, anidatedView: 143, state: 60.77, warningHighThreshold: 90, dangerHighThreshold: 101, lvl: 3, children: []}, {id: 195, idParent: 141, anidatedView: 436, state: 59.13, warningHighThreshold: 90, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}]}]


console .log (collectMax (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Original answer

Here is a non-mutating version that seems to do what you want, returning a new object with the maximum values rolled up to their ancestors:

```js
const collectMax = (xs) => xs .map (({children, kids = collectMax (children), ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  state: Math.max (rest.state, ... kids .map (k => k .state)),
  warningHighThreshold: Math .max (rest .warningHighThreshold, ... kids .map (k => k .warningHighThreshold)),
  dangerHighThreshold: Math .max (rest. dangerHighThreshold, ... kids .map (k => k .dangerHighThreshold)),
  children: kids
}))

const list = [{id: 100, idParent: null, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 1, children: [{id: 139, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 186, idParent: 139, anidatedView: 279, state: 15.58, warningHighThreshold: 80, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}, {id: 189, idParent: 139, anidatedView: 193, state: 40.65, warningHighThreshold: 80, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}, {id: 140, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 193, idParent: 140, anidatedView: 183, state: 65.41, warningHighThreshold: 92, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}, {id: 141, idParent: 100, anidatedView: null, state: null, warningHighThreshold: null, dangerHighThreshold: null, lvl: 2, children: [{id: 194, idParent: 141, anidatedView: 143, state: 60.77, warningHighThreshold: 90, dangerHighThreshold: 101, lvl: 3, children: []}, {id: 195, idParent: 141, anidatedView: 436, state: 59.13, warningHighThreshold: 90, dangerHighThreshold: 100, lvl: 3, children: []}]}]}]

console .log (
  collectMax (list)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by recursively applying the function to the `children` node, then combine our test value together with the appropriate value from each child, and take the maximum, assigning the current object that maximum for the appropriate property.

But I think it would be cleaner to pull out a helper function from this:

```js
const collect = (ps, o, k) => Object.assign (... ps .map (p => ({
  [p]: Math.max (o [p], ... k .map (k => k [p]))
})))

const collectMax = (xs) => xs .map (({children, kids = collectMax (children), ...rest}) => ({
  ... rest,
  ... collect (['state', 'warningHighThreshold', 'dangerHighThreshold'], rest, kids),
  children: kids
}))
```

This does the same thing but slightly simplifies the code and makes it trivial to add new maximum-valued properties.

Comment: I noticed that this solution does not take the values 'warningHighThreshold' and 'dangerHighThreshold' from the node with the highest 'state' value.  
This solution looks for the maximum 'warningHighThreshold' and 'dangerHighThreshold' regardless of the value of 'state'.

Comment: I missed the "also warningHighThreshold and dangerHighThreshold _of that max node_" requirement.  If I have time I'll try to look at it later today.  But no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to solve the problem.
I leave my solution for those who may have the same issue.

```
const populateState = item => {
  if (item.children.length) {
    const maxValue = item.children
      .map(child => populateState(child))
      .filter(({ state }) => state != null)
      .reduce((maxValue, value) => (value.state > maxValue.state ? value : maxValue), { state: -1 })
    item.state = maxValue.state
    item.warningHighThreshold = maxValue.warningHighThreshold
    item.dangerHighThreshold = maxValue.dangerHighThreshold
    return maxValue
  } else {
    const { state, warningHighThreshold, dangerHighThreshold } = item
    return { state, warningHighThreshold, dangerHighThreshold }
  }
}
```

Usage:
(The **array** variable is the list I`ve defined in the question)

```
populateState({ children: array})
```

Any code enhancement is welcome.

Comment: If you set `dangerHighThreshold` of the very last child to 101, it's parent gets 101, but not parent of the parent and so on.

Comment: I´m taking the values dangerHighThreshold and warningHighThreshold ​​of the node with the maximum state value

Comment: oh, I see. I understood it as independent property.

Comment: [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68271741/12750399) where I manipulate object recursively with Depth First Search implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const list = JSON.parse(`[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "idParent": null,
        "anidatedView": null,
        "state": null,
        "warningHighThreshold": null,
        "dangerHighThreshold": null,
        "lvl": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 139,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 186,
                        "idParent": 139,
                        "anidatedView": 279,
                        "state": 15.58,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 80,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 189,
                        "idParent": 139,
                        "anidatedView": 193,
                        "state": 40.65,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 80,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 140,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 193,
                        "idParent": 140,
                        "anidatedView": 183,
                        "state": 65.41,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 92,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 141,
                "idParent": 100,
                "anidatedView": null,
                "state": null,
                "warningHighThreshold": null,
                "dangerHighThreshold": null,
                "lvl": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 194,
                        "idParent": 141,
                        "anidatedView": 143,
                        "state": 60.77,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 90,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 101,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 195,
                        "idParent": 141,
                        "anidatedView": 436,
                        "state": 59.13,
                        "warningHighThreshold": 90,
                        "dangerHighThreshold": 100,
                        "lvl": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]`);

function getHigh(obj, prop)
{
  let ret = null;
  for(let n = 0; n < 2; n++)
  {
    for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
      const r = getHigh(obj[i].children, prop);
      if (r > obj[i][prop])
      {
        obj[i][prop] = r;
        ret = r;
      }

      if (obj[i][prop] > ret)
        ret = obj[i][prop];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log("warningHighThreshold", getHigh(list, "warningHighThreshold"));
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 2));
console.log("dangerHighThreshold", getHigh(list, "dangerHighThreshold"));
console.log(JSON.stringify(list, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem could be solve with depth first search...

```js
let input = [{ "id": 100, "idParent": null, "anidatedView": null, "state": null, "warningHighThreshold": null, "dangerHighThreshold": null, "lvl": 1, "children": [{ "id": 139, "idParent": 100, "anidatedView": null, "state": null, "warningHighThreshold": null, "dangerHighThreshold": null, "lvl": 2, "children": [{ "id": 186, "idParent": 139, "anidatedView": 279, "state": 15.58, "warningHighThreshold": 80, "dangerHighThreshold": 100, "lvl": 3, "children": [] }, { "id": 189, "idParent": 139, "anidatedView": 193, "state": 40.65, "warningHighThreshold": 80, "dangerHighThreshold": 100, "lvl": 3, "children": [] }] }, { "id": 140, "idParent": 100, "anidatedView": null, "state": null, "warningHighThreshold": null, "dangerHighThreshold": null, "lvl": 2, "children": [{ "id": 193, "idParent": 140, "anidatedView": 183, "state": 65.41, "warningHighThreshold": 92, "dangerHighThreshold": 100, "lvl": 3, "children": [] }] }, { "id": 141, "idParent": 100, "anidatedView": null, "state": null, "warningHighThreshold": null, "dangerHighThreshold": null, "lvl": 2, "children": [{ "id": 194, "idParent": 141, "anidatedView": 143, "state": 60.77, "warningHighThreshold": 90, "dangerHighThreshold": 100, "lvl": 3, "children": [] }, { "id": 195, "idParent": 141, "anidatedView": 436, "state": 59.13, "warningHighThreshold": 90, "dangerHighThreshold": 100, "lvl": 3, "children": [] }] }] }]
let keys = ["state", "warningHighThreshold", "dangerHighThreshold"];

function populateState(children) {
    for (let item of children)
        Object.assign(item, populateState(item.children))

    return children.length
        ? Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: Math.max(...children.map(o => o[k])) })))
        : {}
}

console.log("Max Threshold:", populateState(input), "\n\nInput:", input)
```